# Generate primefaces ajax tree on demand?

Tags: ajax, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, ejb

I have a project using JSF primefaces and EJB managed Beans with hibernate storage.
 http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeAjax.jsf

Question: I keep on getting a out of memory or stack overflow errors can you see a problem with my recursion?

```
@ManagedBean(name = "categoryController")
@RequestScoped
public class CategoryController implements Serializable {
    ...

    @EJB
    private CategoryFacade ejbFacade;
    private TreeNode root;

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        System.out.print("Facade value=" + getFacade());
        Category categoryRoot = getFacade().find(new Integer(1));
        getSubcategories(categoryRoot, root);

    }

    private void getSubcategories(Category categoryRoot, TreeNode root) {
        List<Category> list = getFacade().findByNamedQuery("Category.findByPCatid", "pcatid", categoryRoot);
        Iterator<Category> it = list.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Category subcategory = it.next();
            TreeNode nextNode = new DefaultTreeNode(subcategory.getUcatid(), root);
            getSubcategories(subcategory, nextNode);

        }

    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You are getting into an infinite loop. Are you sure that *all* subcategories doesn't have a (grand)child that was the subcategory's (grand)father once? If that happens, you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: There was one case the root node, that solved the infinite loop; Thanks.

Comment: @RinaldoPJr you should post that comment in an answer so OP could accept it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP edited the question after my comment, since it wasn't the main topic. It became about "the best way" to do it. Now, he edited again, saying that he still getting those errors. I don't know what the OP wants now. :P

Comment: Please post answer about recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your recursion is in an infinite loop on your root element.
try adding this:

```
if (!subcategory.getCatid().equals(new Integer(1))) {
     getSubcategories(subcategory, nextNode);
}
```

You can also look up the Primefaces event listeners to generate the tree on demand.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeEvents.jsf